# Webpack imports a very large existing chunk even if only a few modules are used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-vue

I’m working with Webpack 5 and trying to optimize the `splitChunks` configuration in a multi page application with a PHP backend and a Vue frontend.

In order to reduce the size of the vendor file I have started excluding some libraries by customizing the test function of the vendor `cacheGroup`.

```js
test(module /* , chunk */) {
  if (module.context) {
    // only node_modules are needed
    const isNodeModule = module.context.includes('node_modules');
    // but we exclude some specific node_modules
    const isToBundleSeparately = [
      'marked', // only needed in one component
      'braintree-web', // only payment page
      'bootstrap/js',
    ].some(str => module.context.includes(str));
    if (isNodeModule && !isToBundleSeparately) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
},
```

By doing so, some libraries that are not used in all pages are only imported in the components that need them, because those components are imported via dynamic imports and are extracted to separate chunks.

This has proven to work as expected until I encountered a strange behavior with one specific chunk and with one specific library (BootstrapVue).

If I add `'bootstrap-vue'` to the list of excluded libraries, what happens is that two components of the library, `BTab` and `BTabs`, are extracted to a very large chunk which also includes the whole code for the payment page and all the libraries used in that page.

[image: Webpack Bundle Analyzer screenshot showing the large chunk]

If you look at the screenshot, the file is the one whose name starts with “init-initPaymentGateway”.

So now all the pages that need those  two BootstrapVue components are loading that large file, including the product page and other pages that only need the two tiny BootstrapVue components.

Here you can see that the chunk is imported in the product page:

[image: Google Chrome Screenshot showing the imported file in the Network Tab]

I would expect that with my current configuration those two components would go to a separate chunk, or, if they are too small, they should be duplicated. Using Webpack Bundle Analyzer I see both very small files and duplicated library files, so I don’t understand why this is not happening with those specific components. The BootstrapVue `BAlert` component, for example, which is also small, is duplicated in different components.

I suspect that the issue comes from the fact that the components are small, but by setting `minSize` to `0` (or `10`) I would expect to not have a minimum size for the creation of chunks.

Here are the imports in the payment page:

```js
import { BTab, BTabs } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import dataCollector from 'braintree-web/data-collector';
```

(Then other inner components import other files from `braintree-web`).

Here is the import in one component of the product page:

```js
import { BTabs, BTab } from 'bootstrap-vue';
```

And here is the complete `splitChunks` configuration (I have removed some of the excluded libraries from the list in the test function as they are not relevant).

```js
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all',
  minSize: 10,
  minChunks: 1,
  maxAsyncRequests: 30,
  maxInitialRequests: 30,
  enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,

  name(module, chunks /* , cacheGroupKey */) {
    const allChunksNames = chunks
      .filter(item => item.name !== null)
      .map(item => item.name.replace('View', ''))
      .join('~');
    return allChunksNames.slice(0, 30);
  },
  cacheGroups: {
    default: {
      minChunks: 2,
        priority: -20,
        reuseExistingChunk: true,
      },
      defaultVendors: {
        name: 'vendor',
        priority: -10,
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 1,
        reuseExistingChunk: true,
        test(module /* , chunk */) {
          if (module.context) {
            // only node_modules are needed
            const isNodeModule = module.context.includes('node_modules');
            // but we exclude some specific node_modules
            const isToBundleSeparately = [
              'marked', // only needed in one component
              'bootstrap-vue',
              'braintree-web',
              'bootstrap/js',
            ].some(str => module.context.includes(str));
            if (isNodeModule && !isToBundleSeparately) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        return false;
      },
    },
  },
},
```

To fix the issue I removed `'bootstrap-vue'` from the exclusion in the test function, but I’d like to understand if I can improve my configuration or at least the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trying to fix another issue caused by a naming collision, I have modified the `name` function and fixed the issue.
Basically the slice function was causing a naming collision, which resulted in a chunk containing the code for more than one module, because both had the same name.

An explanation is given in the Webpack docs:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksminsize, but it wasn't very clear to me until I experienced this issue:

> ##### Warning
>
> When assigning equal names to different split chunks, all vendor modules are placed into a single shared chunk, though it's not recommend since it can result in more code downloaded.

A simple fix was to increase the length of the name by changing the last line from

```js
return allChunksNames.slice(0, 30);
```

to

```js
return allChunksNames.slice(0, 40);
```

But I still had the feeling that in some moment another naming clash could come up. I tried removing the slice part but it resulted in a Webpack error complaining about a name that was too long.

So in the end the long term solution was to simply delete the `name` function, and let Webpack assign a name.

```
name(module, chunks /* , cacheGroupKey */) {
  const allChunksNames = chunks
    .filter(item => item.name !== null)
    .map(item => item.name.replace('View', ''))
    .join('~');
  return allChunksNames.slice(0, 40);
}
```

The resulting names are less clear, but I can always figure out what each chunk contains by using the Webpack Bundle Analyzer plugin.

Here is the chunk containing only the two modules that are needed in the product page.

[image: The chunk with only the modules that I need]